# New Thread (Exe Process) not working from localhost (IIS)

Tags: asp.net

I need to create new thread in existing asp.net web application and it should be running on background. And i have tested it with following simple code

`protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
        }`

When i run this application it's working fine with asp.net debugger but when i hosted this application to localhost (IIS) and run from that then it will not open notepad file.

I have  also given

identity impersonate="true" userName ="userid" password ="pwd" >

in web.config but still it is not working

Please help me to resolve this issue.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account under which an asp.net application runs, has very limited permissions by default. You need to configure the permissions to run an application on the server.
Read this Microsoft support link - [Unable to Start a Process from ASP.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555134).
You may also Google on how to set ASP.NET account permissions depending on the IIS version that you are using.

Hope this helps!